# How to receive an HttpRequest in ASP.NET MVC on page load?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, httprequest, httpresponse

I am making a website that will be embedded in another application. The application sends my website some xml via an HTTP request. I need to receive and parse that xml, and then display my web page after I get the data from it.

How do I do this in MVC? Am I supposed to do this in my Home Controller? There is no Page_Load function. Do I do this in my somewhere in my `Index` function?

```
public ActionResult Index(){

    //Am I supposed to do this here?

    return View();
}
```

Could I get a code example, please?

Comment: Action methods respond to HTTP requests, as defined in routes.  There is no concept of a page.

Comment: @Slaks I'm not sure what that means. Do you mean in RouteConfig.cs? What do I need to define and how? And then what do I do in my action method - do I return the View, or the HTTP response? How? What do you mean by "page"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index(string xml)
{
    // parse xml into some custom model class
    XmlParserModel model = ParseXml(xml);
    return View(model);
}
```

Next create a strongly-typed-to `XmlParseModel` class an `index.cshtml` page in the `home` folder page and enter in whatever you wanted to output from the parsed xml.

Comment: This seems so easy! Is there a specific way the HTTP request would have to be sent in order for it to work with this? Would it be too much trouble for you to provide an example of that, too?

Comment: You can do a GET, POST, whatever you want the way that method is set up. Honestly look up any basic asp.net mvc tutuorial and you should be on your way

Comment: If you are sending an XML document, I would recommend POSTing it and not using GET.

Comment: Returning View(model) sends the application the code/text of my Index.cshtml file in the WebResponse. Is there a way to avoid this?